# Стрим видеофайла через сайт

Tags: streaming

Возможно ли организовать на сайте стрим видеофайла? 
Мы с друзьями находимся на данный момент в разных городах и хотели бы посмотреть вместе фильм, но чтобы смотреть, нужно чтобы фильм у всех был на одной и той же секунде(ну, с небольшой погрешностью, конечно).
Стримить через твитч и др. платформы нет возможности - у всех сейчас слабый интернет.

Comment: Возможно, поможет: https://reactphp.org/stream/

Comment: Скачайте заранее файл с фильмом, договоритесь о времени и нажмите кнопку воспроизведения одновременно. У всех фильм будет идти одинаково.

Comment: "был на одной и той же секунде" и "у всех сейчас слабый интернет" — по-моему, немного взаимоисключающие понятия) Но если так хочется, то можно устроить с помощью платформы для проведения автовебинаров, попробуйте через [boomstream](http://boomstream.com). Регистрационного бонуса как раз на фильм должно хватить.